# Why is my GUI still hanging when the slow running code has been moved to a QThread?

Tags: pyside6

I have some slow-running code that I want to run in the background as I open up a new GUI window. I'm using the method outlined in [this article](https://realpython.com/python-pyqt-qthread/#using-qthread-to-prevent-freezing-guis) to move my slow-running code into a QThread using moveToThread.

It seems very much like I've moved the code successfully into the new thread because I can insert the following code just before my slow-running code and see the print statements show up without interfering with my GUI at all.

```
for i in range(5):
    time.sleep(1)
    print(f"sleep {i}")
```

Once I get past this code into my real slow-running code the GUI locks up until the code is complete.

How do I continue troubleshooting from here? Most of the slow-running code has to do with regex searches. I could try to reproduce some simplified version of the actual code that's causing the problem but I'm more interested in learning how I should actually go about looking into this problem further myself. I don't know what tools I have available to help me figure out why this is happening.

Comment: Remember that Python doesn't directly allow real thread concurrency. If the "slow-running" code is CPU demanding, and doesn't periodically return control to other threads, doing that computation in a separate thread is almost the same as doing it in the main one due to the GIL. If you have some for/while loops that are fundamental parts of the computation, consider just doing them in the main thread and periodically call `QApplication.processEvents()`. Alternatively, periodically add `self.msleep(1)` within the thread (`processEvents()` only works for events in the *calling* thread).

Comment: create a [mre].

Comment: @musicamante to the rescue again! As always, thank you for your help.